# How to convert tensorflow model to keras model? .pb file to .hdf5?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, machine-learning-model

I have searched for hours on google but have not seen any code/package to convert.
Any guidance on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375679/tensorflow-pb-format-to-keras-h5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow (.pb) format to Keras (.h5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375679/tensorflow-pb-format-to-keras-h5)

Answer (score 1):

Use `tf.keras.models.load_model('Model')`

Instead of  `tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model.pb')`

Check similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/62211811/14290244
Well explained about conversion of .pb to .H5 format.