# Tensorflow (.pb) format to Keras (.h5)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to convert my model in Tensorflow (.pb) format to Keras (.h5) format to view post hoc attention visualisation. 
I have tried below code.

```
file_pb = "/test.pb"
file_h5 = "/test.h5"
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_pb)
tf.keras.models.save_keras_model(loaded_model, file_h5)
loaded_model_from_h5 = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_h5)
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Latest `Tensorflow Version (2.2)`, when we `Save` the Model using `tf.keras.models.save_model`, the Model will be `Saved` in not just a `pb file` but it will be Saved in a Folder, which comprises `Variables` Folder and `Assets` Folder, in addition to the `saved_model.pb` file, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Saved Model Folder]

For example, if the `Model` is `Saved` with the Name, **`"Model"`**, we have to `Load` using the Name of the Folder, "Model", instead of `saved_model.pb`, as shown below:

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Model')
```

instead of

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model.pb')
```

One more change you can do is to replace

```
tf.keras.models.save_keras_model
```

with

```
tf.keras.models.save_model
```

Complete working Code to convert a Model from `Tensorflow Saved Model Format (pb)` to `Keras Saved Model Format (h5)` is shown below:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

New_Model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Dogs_Vs_Cats_Model') # Loading the Tensorflow Saved Model (PB)
print(New_Model.summary())
```

Output of the `New_Model.summary` command is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               3211776   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,453,121
Trainable params: 3,453,121
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Continuing the code:

```
# Saving the Model in H5 Format and Loading it (to check if it is same as PB Format)
tf.keras.models.save_model(New_Model, 'New_Model.h5') # Saving the Model in H5 Format

loaded_model_from_h5 = tf.keras.models.load_model('New_Model.h5') # Loading the H5 Saved Model
print(loaded_model_from_h5.summary())
```

Output of the command, `print(loaded_model_from_h5.summary())` is shown below:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               3211776   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,453,121
Trainable params: 3,453,121
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

​
As can be seen from the `Summary` of both the `Models` above, both the `Models` are same.

Comment: I got this error in saving the model
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'

Comment: This is like a dream-come-true convention but I got this error: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'. I am running on Tensorflow Version (2.3).

Comment: I got this AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'

Comment: I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'Summary'?

Comment: I got :   if (not model._is_graph_network and  # pylint:disable=protected-access
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'