# Convert a saved model (.pb) to a keras model (.h5)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have code like the following:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(input_model_path)
```

and my input is a model.pb.

I now want to convert it to keras .h5 but I don't know how to do this.
Is there a way to convert this saved model to keras format directly?

I also tried doing it with

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(input_model_path)
```

but this gives me another error (IndexError)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow (.pb) format to Keras (.h5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375679/tensorflow-pb-format-to-keras-h5)

Comment: Nope, with that I get the following error:

IndexError: list index (0) out of range

Comment: As this is my second day trying this and finding people also having the same problems. I am not going to continue with this saved_model and instead will create a keras model from start on. Proof of the non-existence of the conversion: github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5273 These ones also state that it is almost impossible without a ton of work.. :) github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42425 github.com/lobe/lobe-python/issues/27