# Is it possible to convert model from .pb or .ckpt to keras model, without knowing the model in advance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

i have a saved_model.pb file and a .ckpt file for a tensorflow model.
I need to recover the summary of the model. I tried this code:

```
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
loaded.summary()
```

But i get this error:

> AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'summary'

I have found out that the reason i get this error is that my model is a tensorflow model and not a keras model, and that I have to convert it into a keras model. However, all the solutions i found assume that i know the structure of the model, which i do not know.
Is there a way to convert the saved_model.pb or the .ckpt file directly in a keras model, without building it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow (.pb) format to Keras (.h5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375679/tensorflow-pb-format-to-keras-h5)

Comment: No, if I load it directly with keras i get:

IndexError: list index (0) out of range