# Unable to load .pb while converting PyTorch model to tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, onnx

### Context

I'm using tf.keras for a personal project and I need to retrieve a pretrained Alexnet model.
Unfortunately, this model is not directly accessible using tf.keras only, so I downloaded the pretrained model using PyTorch, converted it into an onnx file and then exported it as a .pb file with the following code :

```
torch_pretrained = torchvision.models.alexnet()
torch_pretrained.load_state_dict(torch.load("alexnet.pth"))

dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224))
torch.onnx.export(torch_pretrained, dummy_input, "alexnet_pretrained.onnx")

onnx_pretrained = onnx.load("alexnet_pretrained.onnx")
onnx_pretrained = prepare(onnx_pretrained)
onnx_pretrained.export_graph('alexnet')
```

### Issue

I'm now trying to retrieve the .pb file using keras as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375679/tensorflow-pb-format-to-keras-h5) with the following code :

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("alexnet")
model.summary()
```

And i get an error :

> AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'

I also get a warning while loading the model, but I don't think it's relevant :

> WARNING:tensorflow:SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5 detected when loading Keras model. Please ensure that you are saving the model with model.save() or tf.keras.models.save_model(), *NOT* tf.saved_model.save(). To confirm, there should be a file named "keras_metadata.pb" in the SavedModel directory.

The loaded model has a very obscure type as you can see :

> <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.._UserObject object at 0x0000023137981BB0>

While doing my researches, I found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8990) which means I'm not the only one to face this issue.

### Question

The easiest way would be to solve this specific issue, but if anyone knows of another way to load a pretrained Alexnet model to tf.keras, this would also solve my actual problem.

### Specs

```
Windows 10
python 3.9.7
tensorflow 2.6.0
torch 1.10.2
torchvision 0.11.3
onnx 1.10.2
onnx-tf 1.9.0
```

Comment: the loaded model is not a keras model. to convert pytorch to keras, check out https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

I followed the suggestion of Jakub : I installed "pytorch2keras" (see [this](https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras)).
I just ran the function to convert directly the pytorch model into a keras model, and it actually worked.

I only had to modify the code of the module as there were some depencies issues (they are using onnx.optimizer, which is now called onnxoptimizer) so I just changed the import line in  :

from

```
from onnx import optimizer
```

to

```
import onnxoptimizer as optimizer
```